# I'm doing some scheme homework that involves recursive functions and I'm very confused

Tags: recursion, scheme

For my class I need to write a function that accepts a string and add "op" after every consonant found in the string.

What I've got so far is a helper function that checks an individual letter to see if it is a consonant or a vowel. here it is:

```
(define (check-letter letter)

(if (null? letter)
  'empty

(or (char=? letter #\a) (char=? letter #\e)
    (char=? letter #\i) (char=? letter #\o)
    (char=? letter #\u) (char=? letter #\y))))
```

So that will give me a true or false for a given letter but I'm not sure how to approach the rest of the problem.

I know I need to use the "string->list" function but I'm very bad with recursive functions.

If anybody could help out and point me in the right direction or somewhere on the internet that might help that would be fantastic

Answer (score 1):

So your initial procedure checks if a char is a vowel. The parameter is a char, no need to check for `null` here. Also, it's a predicate (returning true or false) so let's call it `vowel?`:

```
(define (vowel? letter)
  (or (char=? letter #\a) (char=? letter #\e)
      (char=? letter #\i) (char=? letter #\o)
      (char=? letter #\u) (char=? letter #\y)))
```

The wrapper function transforming a string to list and back is trivial:

```
(define (add-op str op)
  (list->string
   (add-op-list (string->list str) op)))
```

Now the recursive function, working on a list. You know that a list is constructed as:

```
`(cons elt1 (cons elt2 (cons elt3 (cons elt4 (.... (cons '() ))))))`
```

and that recursivity means that

1. you process the first element (obtained by `car`), and call the same procedure on the rest of the list (obtained by `cdr`)
2. until you reach your base case (here, list is `null?`, so add the final `'()`)

So this leads to:

```
(define (add-op-list lst op)
  (if (null? lst) ; list is empty: finally add '()
      '()
      (let ((c (car lst))) ; c is the first element of the list
        (if (vowel? c)     ; is it a vowel?
            (cons c          (add-op-list (cdr lst) op)) ; yes, just add it to the resulting list and proces the rest
            (cons c (cons op (add-op-list (cdr lst) op))))))) ; no, add c and op
```

Trying:

```
> (add-op "Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious" #\!)
"S!up!er!c!al!if!r!ag!il!is!t!ic!ex!p!ial!id!oc!ious!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tail-recursive solution (your teacher will surely give you extra-credit for using tail recursion!):

```
(define (vowel? c)
  (member c '(#\a #\e #\i #\o #\u #\y)))

(define (homework-1 string punc)
  (let extending ((letters (string->list string)) (result '()))
    (cond ((null? letters) 
           (list->string (reverse result)))

          ((vowel? (car letters))
           (extending (cdr letters)
                      (cons (car letters) result)))

          (else
           (extending (cdr letters)
                      (cons punc (cons (car letters) result))))

> (homework-1 "abc" #\-)
"ab-c-"
```